# ERROR: apt is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play

Tags: ansible

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a YML file:-

```
user@ubuntuA:~$ ansible-playbook -i hostfile setup.yml
```

**ERROR**:

> apt is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play

Ansible version: 1.9.2

yml-file:-

```
---

- name: Install MySQL server
  apt: name=mysql-server state=latest

- name: Install Apache module for MySQL authentication
  apt: name=libapache2-mod-auth-mysql state=latest

- name: Install MySQL module for PHP
  apt: name=php5-mysql state=latest
```

Comment: Do you have any other files?

Comment: Also, is the provided yml the setup.yml?

Answer (score 21):

Your yml file should look something like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks: 
  - name: Install packages
    apt:
      name:
      - mysql-server
      - libapache2-mod-auth-mysql
      - php5-mysql
      state: latest
      cache_valid_time: 3600    # update cache if more than an hour old
```

Comment: The second example allows you to loop over a single task instead of listing three separate tasks

Comment: Getting the same error while writing simple ansible-role with some basic Linux packages. Please help me out

Comment: I can't help you out much without seeing your code. For a role you need a playbook with a "roles" section calling your role by name, and you need a "roles" directory, with a directory beneath that who's name is referenced in your playbook. Beneath that you need a directory called "tasks", and your main.yml should look something like the OP's example

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to execute your setup.yml file directly with ansible-playbook. As @smiler171 mentioned in his answer, correct format for this is the following:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks: 
  - name: Install MySQL server
    apt: name=mysql-server state=latest

  - name: Install Apache module for MySQL authentication
    apt: name=libapache2-mod-auth-mysql state=latest

  - name: Install MySQL module for PHP
    apt: name=php5-mysql state=latest
```

Your current file format is for [imports and includes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html). It is useful if you want to reuse tasks from setup.yml somewhere else. In this case you can create another file (let's say playbook.yml) like that:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks: 
  - import_tasks: setup.yml
```

and run it:

```
ansible-playbook -i hostfile playbook.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, that means that your playbook yml file does not comply with yml syntax. Check for spaces , hyphen etc. Take a look at existing working yml files, like the one pasted by smiller171 in the above answer. I also had a similar error , turned out that my syntax was incorrect.